# Connect an MS Access File to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I need to create a linked table in my MS Access file that is linked to a SQL Server back end.  The file is shared on a network.  Is it possible to create the connection so that it works on any machine that the Access file is run on or do I need to set up a connection on each machine?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a DSN-less connection - have a read here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892490/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-connection-to-sql-server-for-linked-tables-in

Comment: This is a good approach.  Otherwise, you will be stuck updating DSNs on all client machines.  It is possible to have that done through group policy updates... but this can lead to you relying on a lot of stuff that's probably outside your wheelhouse.

Comment: Don't forget the option to use a file DSN, which creates the same "DSN-less" connection, but can be created and implemented through the GUI. Might be easier for some users.